# How can I host multiple IoC-driven WCF services in MVC?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I have around 6 **WCF services** that I want to host in an **MVC application**, routing requests to `/services/foo` to `WcfFooService` and `/services/bar` to `WcfBarService`

I can accomplish **IoC** with StructureMap within the services and inject my constructor dependencies by using the example that Jimmy Bogard blogged about [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/):

Jimmy's article is great, but I'm trying to extend it to work with **multiple services hosted within the same MVC application**. Essentially, the part at the bottom is the part that is causing me a few headaches:

```
public class StructureMapServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    public StructureMapServiceHostFactory()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.AddRegistry<FooRegistry>());
        //var iTriedThisToo = ObjectFactory.Container;
        //container.Configure(x => x.[etc]);
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new StructureMapServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

With a **single** WCF service - routing MVC requests to a specific url *via* the StructureMapServiceHostFactory shown above works brilliantly - but - If (for example) I create a `StructureMapServiceHostFactory2` for the `/services/bar` call, to allow for a different Registry to be used, when the MVC app spins up, it appears to call each factory in turn as it runs through RouteConfig.cs and adds the routes, so ultimately I don't get configured instances that the first ServiceHostFactory should provide.

It doesn't make a difference if I call `Initialize();` or attempt to grab the `Container` property and call `Configure` on it, either.

Am I on a hiding to nothing with this? The major reason for requiring registry isolation is due to different NHibernate configuration, but I *could* configure Named instances of SessionFactory and Session for NHibernate purposes and then use a single registry to get around this. In my mind I wanted the WCF service and MVC-hosting to be capable of using their own IoC containers in isolation, which is why I went down this route.

Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

Comment: 6 WCF services? Wow! I hope you're using message based communication with those WCF services (as [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) explains), otherwise it would probably be pretty painful.

Comment: Interesting article Steven! Thanks for sharing, we certainly could do with a neater architecture like that. It might also be the enabler for what I need....will give it a close look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it would appear the only person capable of answering this was me, by virtue of a re-think and 're-architecting' the solution so that the problem doesn't exist in the first place.

I now have a capable way of hosting these services and maintaining IoC with StructureMap neatly per service, without any conflicting concerns.

If you find yourself in a similar position with SOA taking over (SOATO?) - taking a step back is a good start ;)

Comment: What was the re-architectured solution?